# Attributed string not showing bold and italic text with a specific font

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, uifont

I am receiving an html string which I need to display using UILabel. In case, I don't add UIFont then I see the string as expected.

```
+(NSAttributedString *)getAttributedText:(NSString *)text {
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
return attrStr;
}
```

[image]

But the font is extremely small, so I need to modify it.

```
+(NSAttributedString *)getAttributedText:(NSString *)text {
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSMutableAttributedString *newString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attrStr];
NSRange range = (NSRange){0,[newString length]};
[newString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14.0] range:range];
return newString;
}
```

Now, I see text as

[image]

Any other way of setting font while maintaining the attributes?

Comment: Because Italic and Bold are INSIDE the `UIFont`, so when you replace it, it change it all. You may modify yourself the HTMLString, or iterate throught the `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSAttributedString *)getAttributedText:(NSString *)text {
      text = [text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-size:%fpx;}</style>", 15]];   // Font size that you want to display for text

      NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                               options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                         NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                    documentAttributes:nil
                                                                 error:nil];
}
```

This may help you...!!!

Comment: Hey - can this be used for both font size and name?

Comment: text = [text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>",
                                              "Font Name",
                                              "Font size"]];  but how you will identify which word will be bold or underline. So better to use same same font with large font size.